# Make android device work as bluetooth keyboard

Tags: android, bluetooth, keyboard

I know this question has been answered before but is it possible to emulate an Android device as a generic Bluetooth keyboard for any connected device. It can be any other Android phone, Smart TV, PS, etc i.e. one solution for all type of devices.

If no why?

Comment: What details do you have to start with?

Comment: I have tried connecting it with another android device, it working but kindy laggy, but I gave no idea about the others.